# Avoiding audio transcoding in Unity?

Tags: unity, audio, compression

I'm working on a project where I only have access to MP3s versions of audio tracks I'd like to use. Unity  is trying to be helpful and recompressing everything as Vorbis, [which is not ideal due to quality loss](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Transcoding). Even if I override the audio clip settings and set it to use MP3, Unity still transcodes the file for me, resulting in quality loss. I can set the clip to PCM, which would avoid re-encoding the file into another lossy format, but the resulting file size is too large to be practical.

In a perfect world I would have WAV versions of all the tracks I want to use, but that is not the case. **Is there anyway to tell Unity to use the file the way it is and to leave it alone and not recompress it?**

For the record I am using Unity 5.3.1 and my project target is iOS.

Comment: I also created this question at [Unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1134364/avoiding-audio-transcoding-in-unity.html) to try and get more attention for the issue.